# How to reduce the number of logging message when using log4net in .net core 2.2?

Tags: model-view-controller, log4net, asp.net-core-2.1

I am trying to use log4net in my mvc application which is made in .net core 2.2.
My logs is stored in mysql database instead of files.
Therefore, I used microKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender to be the AdoNetAppender.

Everything works fine. However, there are too many unnecessary logs.

When I start the application, the logs:

```
level   logger
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddlewa
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerA
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerA
FATAL   Log4NetCoreMVC.Utilities.Logger
ERROR   Log4NetCoreMVC.Utilities.Logger
INFO    Log4NetCoreMVC.Utilities.Logger
WARN    Log4NetCoreMVC.Utilities.Logger
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerA
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewRes
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures.ViewRes
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerA
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddlewa
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMi
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMi
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMi
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMi
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.StaticFiles.StaticFileMi
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
INFO    Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Internal.WebHost
```

From the logs, only Log4NetCoreMVC.Utilities.Logger is what I need.

I would like get rid of these messages from other loggers.

My log4net.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<log4net>
  <appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="MicroKnights.Logging.AdoNetAppender, MicroKnights.Log4NetAdoNetAppender">
    <bufferSize value="1" />
    <connectionType value="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection, MySql.Data" />
    <connectionStringName value="log4net" />
    <connectionStringFile value="appsettings.json" />
    <commandText value="INSERT INTO log (datetime,thread,level,logger,message,exception,test) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception,@test);" />
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_date" />
      <dbType value="DateTime" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@thread" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%thread" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@log_level" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="50" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%level" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@logger" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%logger" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@message" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="4000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%message" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@exception" />
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="2000" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.ExceptionLayout" />
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <parameterName value="@test"/>
      <dbType value="String" />
      <size value="255" />
      <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
        <conversionPattern value="%property{test}" />
      </layout>
    </parameter>
  </appender>
  <root>
    <level value="Info" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
</log4net>
```

I tried to modify the

```
<root>
    <level value="Info" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
```

to

```
<root>
    <level value="Warn" />
    <appender-ref ref="AdoNetAppender" />
  </root>
```

It works all level which is lower than 'Warn' are hided.
But I hope I can keep the logs from Log4NetCoreMVC.Utilities.Logger even it is in 'Info' level.

Can I get different level logs from different loggers?

Microsoft or System --> 'Warn' and above

My Custom Logger --> 'Info' and above

Comment: You can specify the source and level in the configuration file. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-3.1#configure-logging

Comment: Thanks Shaggy. I tried modified the appsettings.json but it seems not work. appsettings.json seems not overwrite log4net.config.